# EWS soap request with Chinese content cannot be handled correctly by Exchange server

Tags: javascript, exchangewebservices

all:

I want to send creating calendar item operation request using EWS, and some of my content, for instance, Subject, may content Chinese characters. Here is what my request soap looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Header>
  <RequestServerVersion xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Version="Exchange2007_SP1"/>
</Header>
<Body>
  <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" SendMeetingInvitations="SendToNone">
    <SavedItemFolderId>
      <DistinguishedFolderId xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" Id="calendar"/>
    </SavedItemFolderId>
    <Items>
      <CalendarItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
        <Subject>新建日程</Subject>
        <ReminderIsSet>true</ReminderIsSet>
        <ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>15</ReminderMinutesBeforeStart>
        <Start>2016-06-22T09:00:00</Start>
        <End>2016-06-22T10:00:00</End>
      </CalendarItem>
    </Items>
  </CreateItem>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

I encode this xml with utf-8 and send it to my testing exchange server, and after a while, it displayed on that server, but with question mark in Subject property instead of '新建日程'. All other properties are displayed correctly.

So I wonder where I did wrong that the Chinese content can not be displayed correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the server setup for UTF8? They both have to be, for example if you'd use a mysql server you would also have to do this mysql_set_charset("utf8"); because if you don't it would safe as ????. I think the issue is that it passes through something that doesnt handle it as UTF8

Comment: Also some fonts show ??? instead of chinese characters, make sure it displays in a font that contains Chinese characters. (edit) and you might have to make sure that in your project settings it set to UTF8 often the default is windows-1252 or ISO-8859-1

Comment: @StrahBehry, English is displayed correctly, and I use another client to connect to my exchange account and create calendar item with the same content, It works fine, I can see '新建日程' on my exchange server, so the server settings must be setup for UTF8.

Comment: I tried your soap in the EWSeditor https://ewseditor.codeplex.com/ and it work fine you might want to test this yourself use the 'EWS Post' in the Tool menu. This should tell you if its a server issue or not (I doubt it is). What does the code look like your using to send the request? if you do network capture of that client traffic what does the actually request your sending to the server look like?

Comment: @GlenScales, I captured that traffic and the request is exactly the same as  I posted above.

Comment: What does the response you get back from the server look like (this will also tell people what version of Exchange sp/roll up your using). I would also suggest you try EWSEditor as a point of difference to your code (eg if it works there but your code doesn't you will know where the problem lies)

Comment: @GlenScales, The server just response with response code 'NoError', and also the item id and changekey of the calendar item I just request to create.

Comment: @GlenScales, I tried ewseditor as you suggested, and when I use the example xml to create a calendar item, I get the result as I requested, but when I only change the Subject to "新建日程" in that requesting xml, the subject of that created calendar item is still bunch of question marks.

Comment: The funny thing is, I use another mail client, outlook for example, to create calendar item with Chinese subject, it works fine. So I think the problem is not on the server side. And also, all the element that accept 'text' value have the same problem, it can not display Chinese, even I encode that xml with utf-8.

Comment: Outlook doesn't use EWS it uses MAPI which is a different protocol, I would probably look at what Service Pack/Roll up the server is running as you maybe dealing with a bug that has been resolved in an update

Comment: @GlenScales, I also tries sending a Chinese content message through ewseditor and it failed to display either. But if I use MIMECONTENT (specify it's encoding method to base64) to keep the message I want to create and send that request, I can get the correct message which display Chinese character correctly. Is there any way similar so that I can keep Chinese character in the request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figure out what's wrong. It's in the request header. I found that the header forgot to set charset as utf-8. What a simple but stupid mistake.....